# How do you update multiple columns using Slick Lifted Embedding?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

How do you update multiple columns using Slick Lifted Embedding ? [This document](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1-RC1/lifted-embedding.html#updating) doesn't say much.

I expected it to be something like this

```
Query(AbilitiesTable).filter((ab: AbilitiesTable.type) => ab.id === ability_id).map((ab: AbilitiesTable.type) => (ab.verb, ab.subject)).update("edit", "doc")
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I figured it out. It should be like this

```
val map = Query(AbilitiesTable)
  .filter(_.id === ability_id)
  .map(ab => ab.verb ~ ab.context)

map.update(("", ""))
```

[Typesafe](http://typesafe.com/), why your documentation is so bad ? I have to Google pretty much every silly thing or dig through unit-tests for hours. Please improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Note this only works with updateable ResultSets, which require that you include the ID. If you try to use this without including the ID field in the built query, it will fail.

Comment: Sorry...but what is `AbilitiesTable`? Is this that `TableQuery` object? The class like this: `class CompanyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Company]`?

Answer (score 78):

With recent versions of Slick, this way of writing it works:

```
Users.filter(_.id === filterId)
     .map(x => (x.name, x.age))
     .update(("john", 99))
```

Be careful to remember the extra parentheses if you are updating more than one property otherwise you might get a compiler warning.

Comment: In intellij comma may not work. u can alternative write like this (x.name ~ x.age)

Comment: In Intellij version 2016, the comma seems working fine.

Comment: Don't forget about tuples in `.map(x => (...))`, as well as in `update(("x", "y"))` so double parenthesis.